# My for loop is returning the output as split characters instead of whole strings or integers

Tags: python, list, methods, data-analysis

The first list is created by input, and takes appends a new list, also taken by input function to the first one. But the output is split, not whole strings, but elements of strings. It's the same thing for a list of integers or a list of mixed types. It splits everything into individual characters.
What function or method do I use to stop this, thanks.

## What do I do?

**INPUT**

```
list1 = list(input("Enter the list: "))
list2 = list(input("Enter new list: "))

for i in list2:
    list1.append(i)
print(list(list1))
```

**OUTPUT-**

```
Enter the list: Joy, Adam, Ben, James
Enter new list: Dave, Ada, Elle

['J', 'o', 'y', ',', ' ', 'A', 'd', 'a', 'm', ',', ' ', 'B', 'e', 'n', ',', ' ', 'J', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's', 'D', 'a', 'v', 'e', ',', ' ', 'A', 'd', 'a', ',', ' ', 'E', 'l', 'l', 'e']
```

Comment: What were you expecting?  You're not using `split` here.  You're converting to a list.  When you convert a string to a list, you get one character per element.

Comment: I thought that the list() typecasting used before the input function is supposed to do that, tell python that any item introduced is part of a list, not a string?

Comment: No.  `list('abcd')` pulls one element at a time from its argument, which in this case means `['a','b','c','d']`.  If you want to split the string on some character, then you use `split`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you meant to use `split`, which you described even though you didn't use it:

```
list1 = input("Enter the list: ").split(', ')
list2 = input("Enter new list: ").split(', ')
list1 += list2
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
Enter the list: One, Two, Three
Enter new list: Four, Five, Six
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, Here is what I did

list1 = list(input("Enter the list: ").split(', '))
list2 = list(input("Enter new list: ").split(', '))
for i in list2:
    list1.append(i)
print(list(list1))

Comment: YOU DON'T NEED THOSE CASTS.  `split` returns a list, and when you print, `list1` is already a list.  Remove the casts.  Follow my example.